# How do I exclude a worksheet from the page number total?

Tags: excel

I want to add page numbers to my spreadsheet when I print it, but i dont want some of the sheets to be counted when it calculates the `&[Pages]` total. The workbook has 4 sheets, 3 need to be printed, but I only want page numbers for the first two sheets. Is this possible without VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hiding the worksheets you don't want to print.

If you select `Print Entire Workbook` in the print dialogue, it will count all the pages visible in the workbook. I made a simple workbook, put the number of pages in the header, and then compared the number of pages in the print preview before and after hiding one of the pages.

If for some reason you don't want to hide the worksheet, even just for the print job, you could also select `Print Active Sheets` after selecting the worksheets you do want to print. (Standard Ctrl/Shift selection rules apply to the worksheet tabs.)

If you are trying to exclude something like a cover page, then I don't think this is possible without VBA. To pull it off, you can leverage the `Workbook_BeforePrint` function.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pages As Integer

    pages = 0        
    ' Count the number of pages visible on each desired sheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws Then 'Modify to fit your criteria
            pages = pages + (ws.HPageBreaks.Count + 1) * (ws.VPageBreaks.Count + 1)
        End If
    Next

    ' Update the header or footer with the desired values.
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If ws Then 'Modify to fit your criteria
            ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "3"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't really work for what I want. I want to print sheets 1-3, but I want &[Pages] to only display the number of pages in sheet 1 and 2

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you'll need to use VBA then. I've added some code to help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I think I will change the last instruction to `ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&[Page] of 3"`